# How to set bottom_margin equal to its height?

Tags: android, layout

I want to set bottom margin equal to view's/layout's height.

```
 <FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    //Main layout
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        .
        .
        .
    </LinearLayout>

    //Bottom drawer layout
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        .
        .
        .
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

How to add bottom margin to second child exactly of its height so that it goes out of the screen?
Is it possible through xml attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant get height of a view in xml.

You can get height of a view dynamically by using ViewTreeObserver, then you can set the margin for that View.

Below is a way you can do dynamically:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutid);

final ViewTreeObserver vto = linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            //get LayoutWidth and height here
            int layoutWidth = linearLayout.getWidth();
            int layoutHeight = linearLayout.getHeight();

            //set layout margin here
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = linearLayout.getLayoutParams();
            llp.bottomMargin = layoutHeight;
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(llp);

            //Then remove layoutChange Listener
            ViewTreeObserver vto = linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```